# Search terms with dollar signs ($) are ignored

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, special-characters

When searching for "MON$ATTACHMENTS"" it searches for "MONATTACHMENTS".

Likewise, searching for "MON$ATTACHMENTS" still searches for "MONATTACHMENTS".

It seems like it is impossible to search for something with a $ (dollar sign) in it.

It should have found (at least) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923/id-ing-deadlocks-in-a-thread-using-firebird).

Comment: You'll have to use Bing or some other search engine.

Comment: Most search engines (including Bing) strip special characters out before doing the search.  Trying to search for file system paths is very frustrating.

I raised a similar question over here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52834/improvements-to-search-functionality-for-technical-people

It would be very nice for a site aimed at technical people to have a tech-friendly search function.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting it appears to work, at least now in 2012:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22MON%24ATTACHMENTS%22

Note that if you're specifically looking for a value in *code* (such as a $-prefixed variable in PHP), you can use the semi-secret `code:` operator to do so: [code:"$i"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A"%24i") vs. ["$i"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%24i) (the latter finds occurrences of "i" without the $ prefix).