# How to search questions which have the dollar sign, $, in their titles?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search terms with dollar signs ($) are ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39874/search-terms-with-dollar-signs-are-ignored)

How to search questions which have the dollar sign, $, in the question titles?

Comment: You can try [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/) either directly or with [this user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3181/symbolhound-search "SymbolHound Search") I wrote.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear if you're just looking to search for terms containing the dollar sign, or if you're looking to constrain this specifically to titles. If the linked question's answer doesn't work for you, please include an example of something you're trying to find...