# Searching for special characters in code works for questions, but not answers

Tags: bug, code-formatting, search

The search question [`code:"\@startsection" is:question` on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22%5C%40startsection%22+is%3Aquestion) should yield all questions that have `\@startsection` written in code:

[image]

The [identified question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) has a number of answers, the [top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31795/5764) [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31793/5764) of which both contain `\@startsection` in code:

[image]

[image]

However, when [switching the search to only show answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=code%3a%22%5c%40startsection%22%20is%3aanswer) (via `is:answer` rather than `is:question`) none of these show. Why is that?

I believe this has to do with the way code is searched, but I'm unable to figure out how to search for this properly. And I'm not interested in using [SymbolHound](http://www.symbolhound.com/), since the search works for questions.

I've already checked these references:

- [How to search for special characters on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38968/168244)
- [Search terms with dollar signs (`$`) are ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39874/168244)
- [Is it possible to search for punctuation/special characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32879/168244)

Comment: In two words: "whole word". The current Stack Exchange search algorithm is searching whole words only, for good or for bad. The answers you linked to *contains* the term, but as part of longer "word" i.e. without any blank space to separate them e.g. `\@startsection{<name>}...` or `\@startsection=macro`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: [This search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=href+run) [does show](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw1Il.png) that one can search within code properly (without using the `code:` prefix). However, I'm still baffled by the possibility to do the same with special characters typically used in [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: Right, something then is weird here.

Comment: SymbolHound appears to [have been broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).